# Location of time.h -> localtime() implemenation in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I am searching for the implementation of localtime() function in time.h. I see that different platforms have different locations for source of c library. I wanted to know the location in Ubuntu 14.04? If by default source is not included in OS, please let me know how to download source or online location of the source. 
Thanks.

Comment: Normally the source for libc is not present on linux distributions. Only the headers.

Comment: In that case, any online location where I can see implementation of localtime() ? Curious to know how time zone information is retrieved and processed...

Comment: Do `apt-get source libc6` from your home and you'll find libc6's sources in a new folder in your home-directory.

Comment: The (gnu) source for libc. BTW: I guess the timezone-info is compiled into some kind of skip list.

Comment: Ok, 1st check which binary your system uses as libc implementation, then check which package provides this binary, finally  `apt-get source` this package's sources. My former comment assumed the package to be `libc6`.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the libc6. Found the source under /time/ folder spread in localtime.c, tzset.c, and tzfile.c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check which binary your system uses as libc implementation.

   To do so compile a minimal C program and run ldd on it:

   ```
   ldd a.out
   ```

   You might get something like this:

   ```
   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff429c6000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f21cdcb7000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f21ce05e000)
   ```

   From this you can pull the info libc is proided by `libc6.so.6`.
2. Check which package provides this binary.

   Search the package providing the file found under 1.:

   ```
   dpkg -S libc.so.6
   ```

   You might get:

   ```
   libc6-i386: /lib32/libc.so.6
   libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
   ```

   The above output tells you, that there are two packages providing the file. Here it's the 32 bit and 64 bit implementation.
3. Decide which one you want and do `apt-get source` this package's sources.

Assuming the package would be `libc6`, do

```
apt-get source libc6
```

and find thre source in a directory inside the current directory.

Comment: I think it should be libc.so.6 instead of libc6.so.6 ?